# paste columns where collapse parameter depends on column class

Tags: r

I'm trying to find a solution to paste all columns of a data table where the "collapse" parameter is set depending on the column class.

Example data:

```
DT <- data.table(Char1 = c('a','b','c','d'), 
             Int1 = c(1:4),
             Char2 = c('e','f','g','h'),
             Int2 = c(5:8))

sapply(DT, class)
      Char1        Int1       Char2        Int2 
"character"   "integer" "character"   "integer"
```

The result needed would be something like this:
Character, POSIX etc. wrapped in quotes but integers, numeric not.

```
"'a', 1, 'e', 5"
"'b', 2, 'f', 6"
"'c', 3, 'g', 7"
"'d', 4, 'h', 8"
```

As a background info...
I want to use this to generate SQL insert statements with correct syntax based on variable classes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `s` is the output of the `sapply` in the question then:

```
fmt <- toString(ifelse(s == "character", "`%s`", "%d"))
DT[, do.call("sprintf", cbind(fmt, .SD))]
```

giving:

```
[1] "`a`, 1, `e`, 5" "`b`, 2, `f`, 6" "`c`, 3, `g`, 7" "`d`, 4, `h`, 8"
```

This variation also works:

```
do.call("sprintf", cbind(fmt, DT))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `shQuote` and `ifelse` like this:

```
# named logical vector for numeric vars
temp <- !sapply(DT, is.numeric)

paste(ifelse(temp, shQuote(names(temp)), names(temp)), collapse=", ")
[1] "'Char1', Int1, 'Char2', Int2"
```

One method to get this to run over all rows is to convert the data.frame to a character matrix and run through the rows with `apply`.

```
apply(as.matrix(DT), 1,
      function(...) paste(ifelse(temp, shQuote(...), ...), collapse=", "))
[1] "'a', 1, 'e', 5" "'b', 2, 'f', 6" "'c', 3, 'g', 7" "'d', 4, 'h', 8"
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but is there a typo? `!sapply` does not work for me.

Comment: Sorry. I fixed that. I switched to using `is.numeric` instead of `class`.